# How to login with Go Jira (Client) on terminal

Tags: terminal, jira

I am trying to login with Go Jira (Client) Using terminal

Command

```
jira login
```

it is asking me for the password, giving personal access token/password in the field is throwing an error.

```
ERROR Post "rest/auth/1/session": unsupported protocol scheme ""
```

I have an SSO login. Also, I don't have the config.yml file created within jira.d folder yet.

Github Link - https://github.com/go-jira/jira

Comment: Please update the question with the link to the library (CMD) you are using.

Comment: Hi, please note that SO is reserved for programming questions. General software (Jira client) usage is better to ask on site SuperUser. It seems that you miss protocol (http:// or https://) in connection endpoint url configuration. How to add it should be in documentation for client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the library requires setting the endpoint:

> You will need to specify your local Jira endpoint first, typically in your homedir like:
>
> ```
> mkdir ~/.jira.d
>
> cat <<EOM >~/.jira.d/config.yml
> endpoint: https://jira.mycompany.com
> EOM
> ```

P.S.
To make it a bit more Go-related, [here is the line that forms the URL](https://github.com/go-jira/jira/blob/v1.0.28/session.go#L37):

```
uri := URLJoin(endpoint, "rest/auth/1/session")
```

That means that the endpoint is not set. And there is no a default value for it.